# Routing error when using devise invitable gem

Tags: ruby, devise-invitable

Getting a No route matches [GET] "/users/invitation/new" error even though it the /invitation/new
new_user_invitation_path is stated under the list of routes.

Using Gem Devise Invitable and using this video for reference: https://youtu.be/5HMWE8g6_tc

tried:

```
rails generate devise_invitable:install
```

```
rails db:migrate
```

```
rails generate devise_invitable:views
```

invitations_controller.rb

```
# app/controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  # GET /users/invitation/new
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /users/invitation
  def create
    super
  end

  # GET /users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=abcdef
  def edit
    # Add any additional logic you need before rendering the invitation acceptance form
    super
  end

  # PUT /users/invitation
  def update
    # Add any additional logic you need after accepting the invitation
    super
  end

  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:name, :other_attributes])
  end
end
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: 'users/invitations' }
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing `config/routes.rb`? Do you have another `devise_for` line in `config/routes.rb`?